# Specifying granted permissions to SQL CLR User Defined Functions for deployment

Tags: .net, sqlclr, database-permissions

I have created a user defined function in .NET 2.0 and am able to successfully deploy it to my local SQL Server instance.  However, I need to grant a specific user `EXECUTE` permission on the function.  I want this to be done in the CLR method itself so that I don't have to manually re-grant the permission every time I redeploy the UDF.  Deploying the CLR function from Visual Studio generates this function in the database:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunction](@input [nvarchar](max))
RETURNS [nvarchar](max) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [LibName].[UserDefinedFunctions].[MyFunction]
GO
```

Is there a way I can have it tack this on:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[MyFunction] TO [wwwUser] AS [dbo]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345099.aspx) - you just create a script called PostDeployScript.sql in your project at the root and it gets automagically appended to the build output.

Note that in VS2012, the Add... dialog has an option to add a script of type "Script (PostDeployment)" or similar - but it then adds the customary "1" to the filename, and that then doesn't work. I've not bothered looking further, although it is also mentioned in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833410%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), because the first method just works.

Comment: Well, that's still somewhat of a manual process, but it appears to be as close as I'll get.  Thanks for the answer.